# Xcode can't delete bridging file

Tags: swift, xcode

I tried download ProgressHUD to my xcode and after adding all my files i clicked to add bridging file also.After i deleted all my files Xcode showed me this

```
error opening input file '/Users/muradshahmammadli/Desktop/Xcode Projects/Instagram/Instagram/Instagram-Bridging-Header.h' (No such file or directory)
```

I'm not trying to open this anywhere what is the problem? i'm using Xcode 9

Comment: Is that your bridging header path is right?

Comment: @Jaydeep nope it is not

Answer (score 1):

The bridging header is specified in your target’s Build Settings. Select your project, then your target, then click Build Settings. Search for “bridging header”. Select it and press delete to remove the custom setting. You may need to clean your target before the error disappears.